# use of double universal selector in a single css stylesheet

Tags: css

I used this CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border:0px none #FFF;
    outline:0 none;
    outline-style:none;
    list-style:none outside;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;
}
```

What I want in my system is, I want to use universal selector for the textarea font only too.

So, if I do `textarea *{font-size=10px;}`, I won't overwrite the previous line code.

I don't want to use inline css for textarea. Any solutions?

Comment: You don't have to do `textarea *` I think just `textarea { font-size:10px }` will work.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: He **can't**, anyway.

Comment: Or just combine the selector: *, textarea { ... }

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: i know that, but i have one problem using spellchecker API which takes the value of universal selector * initially and then further defined value after a keyboard event. so i want to overwrite that universal font size value just for textarea.

Comment: @Frozenfire Then just use `textarea { font-size:10px }` I'm pretty sure that'll do what you want.

Comment: i did...it won't work....the javascript function is taking value inside * initially and then of textarea{ font-size:10px; } after some keyboard event like "pressing space".

Answer (score 0):

The font in textarea's doesn't respond to global selectors. You'll have to target it specifically:

```
textarea
{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: If that doesn't work then try to put "font-size:12px!important;"

Comment: i have one problem using spellchecker API which takes the value of universal selector * initially and then further defined value after a keyboard event. so i want to overwrite that universal font size value just for textarea..